# Animating `visible` property in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, button, label

I have a label named `label1`. When the user clicks `button1`, my label becomes invisible:

```
label1.Visible = false;
```

What can I do to animate this property (for WinForms)?

Comment: How would you animate a boolean property?

Comment: I don't want to animate a boolean property, I want to animate something like `Opacity`, but I want the result to be like it would be with `label1.Visible = false;`

Comment: But, unfortunately, a label doesn't have an `Opacity` property...

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the text colour of the label gradually between your Form's background colour (or transparent if it works) and the final colour.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, WinForms does not support animations like WPF does.
You will have to use a custom solution. For example you can look into using GDI+.

- Make a 'image' of the label ([Example)](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3897.htm)
- Set the visibility of the label to false.
- Use GDI to draw the bitmap using less opacity to simulate the opacity fade.